# Problems with facebook adset setup

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, installation, facebook-php-sdk

Hi I am trying to set up a adset for the Apple App Store (Google Play doesn't give this), but i am facing this error message;

> Missing or invalid field in promoted objects: Application_id must be
>   valid for the APP_INSTALLS optimization goal. Set it in Promoted
>   objects.

I have through topics regarding this, but couldn't find a solution, can you please assist?
Thanks,
E.

Comment: How does your `params` look like? Without that info it would not be possible to fix it. Chances are that you are missing a the `"promoted_object": {"page_id":"<pageID>"}` key value. If that fixes your problem let me know to post an answer with a detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Same Issue here: [application_id needs to be Valid Facebook Ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247111/application-id-needs-to-be-valid-facebook-ad)

I had the exact same error and solved it by changing the app type to Consumer. Unfortunately you cannot just change the type for an existing app, so you have to create a new app and select the right type, see:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types/

I guess that for me the error occured because I chose hte Gaming type which does not support App Events, see link above. The Consumer type worked for me.

Of course you get a new app ID, which you need to put again into the Facebook SDK inside your app, so it is kind of starting all over again.