# application_id needs to be Valid Facebook Ad

Tags: facebook-ads

I'm getting this error after re-creating my entire campaign several times:

> Missing or Invalid Field in Promoted Objects: For optimization goal
> APP_INSTALLS, application_id needs to be valid. Please set it in the
> Promoted Objects. (#1815437)

Have tripple checked every field, but nothing seems out of place?

Answer (score 4):

1. You have to integrate Facebook SDK in your application
2. Publish to application store
3. Try again

OR

You have to change Facebook campaign instead cost per install you should select cost per link click in Ads set

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same error and solved it by changing the app type to Consumer. Unfortunately you cannot just change the type for an existing app, so you have to create a new app and select the right type, see:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types/

I guess that for me the error occured because I chose hte Gaming type which does not support App Events, see link above. The Consumer type worked for me.

Of course you get a new app ID, which you need to put again into the Facebook SDK inside your app, so it is kind of starting all over again.

Comment: tried with change it to consumer type, still the same error

Answer (score 1):

There will be a checkbox option under App Identity field that "Use this page for your ad's identity instead of the app name." You have to check it if you are promoting an Application. This might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I faces the same error and fixed it by going into my app settings (settings -> basic -> ios tab) where I had wrong `bundle id` and I also added `App-Specific Shared Secret` (not sure which of those was the real issue). Then I had to delete the affected campaign and create again to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thus sharing it here.

1. Verify the BundleId/App ID in the FB Developer Console (Most likely, you would have had a wrong id before you created the FB campaign)
2. Correct the BundleID/App ID in FB developer console
3. Delete the FB Ad campaign and re-create it